# Hadoop job accepted but not running Hadoop2.4.1

Tags: hadoop, hadoop2

I had a distributed cluster of Hadoop2.4.1. When i run a sample job it in accepted state but not running.

below is the command prompt where is getting ideal.

```
/usr/local/hadoop/share/hadoop/mapreduce$ hadoop jar hadoop-mapreduce-examples-2.4.1.jar pi 3 2

Number of Maps  = 3
Samples per Map = 2
14/08/12 14:21:18 WARN util.NativeCodeLoader: Unable to load native-hadoop library for your platform... using builtin-java classes where applicable
Wrote input for Map #0
Wrote input for Map #1
Wrote input for Map #2
Starting Job
14/08/12 14:21:20 INFO client.RMProxy: Connecting to ResourceManager at /0.0.0.0:8032
14/08/12 14:21:21 INFO input.FileInputFormat: Total input paths to process : 3
14/08/12 14:21:21 INFO mapreduce.JobSubmitter: number of splits:3
14/08/12 14:21:21 INFO mapreduce.JobSubmitter: Submitting tokens for job: job_1407833440940_0001
14/08/12 14:21:22 INFO impl.YarnClientImpl: Submitted application application_1407833440940_0001
14/08/12 14:21:22 INFO mapreduce.Job: The url to track the job: http://impc1368.htcindia.com:8088/proxy/application_1407833440940_0001/
14/08/12 14:21:22 INFO mapreduce.Job: Running job: job_1407833440940_0001
```

Comment: Once restart hadoop services and try.
working?

Comment: Already tried it but not helpful, also when the systems are removed from cluster the job is running fine on the system which was master, config files were moved from this system to all slaves.But nameNode :50070 shows all slaves

i assume i have to make some config changes so that slaves can appear with the resources so that job can run.

please help

i had observed that when i add master system IP to the slaves file
the job running fine and found that the active node in port :8088 was only master. i am facing difficulty when i remove master system IP from the slaves file.

Comment: What's the output of `jps` in slave nodes?
Check whether datanodes are running in slave nodes

Comment: Yes checked datanode and nodemanager are active on slaves

Comment: SecondaryNameNode
 ResourceManager
 NameNode
on the master machine

Comment: Checked log files for any error?

Comment: Prithvi is it possible to share the email so that i can send u the screen shot of the problem

Comment: please provide me the mail id

Comment: Any solution? I am getting same problem.. need help..

Answer (score -2):

check logs files of nodemanager for java.net.ConnectException,and check config of yarn-site.xml for yarn.resourcemanager.address